How Do I Give rows in a table of contents a key. Then look up the key Later using the data from the rows in table of contents?
I abridged what I'm trying to accomplish on my actual sheet, with a lot of data points to this test.
It should be simple. Associate the "G"values with the "S" values in the table.
I tried to do it myself.
I tried to use AI. To give me fix ideas.
I don't understand how this can be so puzzling.

I included the formula in the picture but here it is:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H="", "", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2:H, {FLATTEN(B2:F7), A2:A7}, 1, False), "No Match"))`)

Please let me know if its simple and I'm just being stupid. because FML
For context to the bigger sheet. Google forms pulls large data into a table, this table then sorts the multiple data points into keys
S is Steam IDs (signup) and G is Group keys (people who want to play together)

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

You may try the following formula-
=MAP(TOCOL(H2:H,1),LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(CHOOSEROWS(A:A,MAX(INDEX(ROW(B2:F7)*(B2:F7=x)))),"No Match")))

Base formula is =CHOOSEROWS(A:A,MAX(INDEX(ROW($B$2:$F$7)*($B$2:$F$7=H2)))) and MAP() is used to make it dynamic spill formula.


@DanielHogg Glad to know it works! If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.

Little bit simpler formula =MAP(TOCOL(H2:H,1),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("",1,INDEX(IF(B2:F7=x,A2:A7,""))))).
